# Pug extends leads to no response from server

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've got an express app set up. Here is one of the routes:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){res.render('index', {});}
```

I know for a fact that this route is triggered and the index page is rendered.

My index.pug is,

```
p some text here
```

This renders successfully.

However, when I change my index.pug file to be,

```
extends layout.pug

block content
    p some text here
```

Then the index.pug is not rendered. Instead, I get no response from the server. Nothing in the terminal, no errors in my browser and console etc.

My layout.pug file has the following,

```
html(lang="en")
body
    block content
```

My index.pug and layout.pug files are in the same directory.

What's going wrong?

Comment: @DevNebulae Nope, none at all

Comment: Try these: no block reference (just static html), remove the .pug filename. Will it output now?

Comment: @DevNebulae Nope. However, if i remove the entire extends line, and the block content, then I get the output

Comment: I would suggest starting over, following the docs, making a really easy example and checking where it goes wrong. Maybe that indicates a problem.

Comment: If this problem has no solution and can't be replicated, please consider deleting it.